# Map of method pointers refactored from map of function pointers - C++

Tags: c++, pointers, function-pointers, pointer-to-member

I was utilizing a map of function pointers with different option values as follows in my `main.cpp` file for different menu items:

```
int main()
{
    while(true)
    {
        printMenu();
        int userOption = getUserOption();
        processMenu(userOption);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

where `void processMenu(int userOption)` is based on a menu of items. Thus, the function is reproduced below:

```
void processMenu(int userOption)
{
    std::map<int, void(*) ()> menu;
         
    menu[1] = printHelp;
    menu[2] = printStats;
    menu[3] = enterData;
    menu[4] = enterText;
    menu[5] = printNextTimestep;
    menu[6] = continue;
    menu[0] = badOptionPrint;
    
    if (userOption > 6 || userOption < 1)
        menu[0]();
    else
        menu[userOption]();
}
```

This map of function pointers worked fine for the purposes of utilizing it within the `main.cpp` file. However, I have recently created a header (`.h`) and corresponding C++ file (`.cpp`) for the Menu related functionality as refactoring. I am trying to replicate such functionality in the `MenuMain.cpp` file:

`MenuMain.cpp`:

```
void MenuMain::processMenu(int userOption)
{
    std::map<int, void(MenuMain::*) ()> menu;
         
    menu[1] = MenuMain::printHelp;
    menu[2] = MenuMain::printStats;
    menu[3] = MenuMain::enterData;
    menu[4] = MenuMain::enterText;
    menu[5] = MenuMain::printNextTimestep;
    menu[6] = MenuMain::continue;
    menu[0] = MenuMain::badOptionPrint;
    
    if (userOption > 6 || userOption < 1)
        menu[0]();
    else
        menu[userOption]();
}
```

Visual Studio gives the following error messages when hovering over the `menu[0]();` and `menu[userOption]();`:

`expression preceding parentheses of apparent call must have (pointer-to-) function type`.

I am trying to figure out if there may be a way to utilize the method pointer map within the class implementation `.cpp` file without upsetting the compiler. Now that the menu options are not being connected to the appropriate methods of the newly refactored `MenuMain` class (which is defined in the appropriate `MenuMain.h` file. Is there a way to get around utilizing function pointers and an analogous member pointer within the `MenuMain` class's implementation `.cpp` file, or is a map of method (or function) pointers not possible due to needing an instance of `MenuMain` to be created prior to a map of method pointers being available?

I have seen some ways to get around this are delegates and potentially creating a new design pattern that can take advantage of this (such as aggregation), but I am would like to keep this as simple as possible as only `MenuMain` will need this map of function pointers that points to the appropriate `MenuMain` methods.

Comment: Pointers to non-static member functions are *not* the same as pointers to non-member functions. A non-static member function needs an object to be called on, and if you don't have that then you can't call the function.

Comment: As an aside: `MenuMain::continue`? That's not a valid name.

Comment: The correct syntax is `menu[1] = &MenuMain::printHelp;`. Note the `&`.

Comment: Do your member functions require a `MenuMain` object to operate?

Comment: Unrelated to the answer I linked you to, you should make `menu` an instance or class variable instead of a local variable.

Comment: The syntax to call is `(this->*menu[0])()` and `(this->*menu[userOption])();`

Comment: Also why don't you make the mapping static and initialize it at the definition? Like `static std::unordered_map<int, void(*)()> const menu = { { 1, printHelp }, ... /* etc... */ };`